# Code::Blocks with GCC compiler compatibility with Windows 7

Tags: compiler-construction, windows-7, ide, compatibility

Is the latest binary release of [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) with [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) setup compatible with Windows 7? If not, is there any way to fix this, or any good alternatives (via switching to a different compiler, different IDE, or both depending on the problem)?

P.S. For those who have used Code::Blocks, will switching IDE's or compiler change the file format of the source code? I know that when I tried Microsoft Visual C++ Express for a bit using the Visual C++ compiler, the file format was different in comparison to the format that Code::Blocks saved source files in.

Comment: Source files are saved in plain-text typically.  Are you referring to line-endings being LF or CRLF?

Comment: Saving as .cpp versus some weird file format that Visual C++ Express uses.

Comment: What do you mean by latest binary release? Did you download from the CB homepage (which is a couple of years old) or as a "nightly" (a new one came out today).

Comment: A cpp file is just plain-text.  You can open it in any text editor.

Comment: I think I'm looking at the download from the CB homepage, which is dated Feb 2008. Where do you find the "nightly"

Comment: Latest nightly is at http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,11844.msg80381/boardseen.html. You probably also want to get the latest version of MinGW at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest CodeBlocks release is fine, however the MinGW setup it provides alongside it is not. I would recommend downloading CodeBlocks standalone, and then getting the latest GCC build from http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/

Answer (score 0):

You could try Qt or Eclipse instead:

http://qt.nokia.com/products

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/